# nginx is not showing custom error page with uwsgi

Tags: nginx, webserver, uwsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to add a custom error page for 502 and 504 answers. Currently I have the following nginx configuration for my site (other configuration files are untouched):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;

    server_name 10.12.112.163;

    add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    charset utf-8;
    try_files $uri @icons;

    error_page 502 504 /502.html;
    location = /502.html {
       root /home/dmoj/site;
       internal;
    }

    location @icons {
        root /home/dmoj/site/resources/icons;
        error_page 403 404 = @uwsgi;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location @uwsgi {
        uwsgi_read_timeout 600;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/dmoj-site.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

When I have uwsgi stopped and take my browser to 10.12.112.163 the default '502 Bad Gateway' message of nginx is showed, however when I go to 10.12.112.163/502.html my page displays perfectly.

I also tested it without the `internal` directive and it is the same.

Comment: Try replacing `error_page 403 404 = @uwsgi;` with `try_files $uri @uwsgi;`

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith! You nailed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's documented somewhere, but I don't think `error_page` can be chained to another `error_page`.

In your case, the `error_page 404` is very similar to the behaviour of the `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

So your chained `error_page` can be replace, like this:

```
location @icons {
    root /home/dmoj/site/resources/icons;
    try_files $uri @uwsgi;
    log_not_found off;
}
```